# Xdebug Remote Debugger seems to jump to random locations

Tags: debugging, location, phpstorm, xdebug

My problem is, that the debugger always stops at the first breakpoint I set (doesn't matter where I set it in the code) but when I continue the execution it seems to jump to a random location in the code. Doesn't make any difference here if I use "step into, "step over" or "continue". I checked if any key on the keyboard is stuck but I can't find anything here and I also cleaned the browser cache and invalidated the PhpStorm caches. After some random time it works normally again and I can step around like I want.

The other weird part is, that it always jumps to the same random location from every set breakpoint, but every breakpoint got another random location.

I am using PhpStorm (latest Version) and Xdebug 2.7 for Remote Debugging with the following configuration

php.ini:

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.7.0alpha1-7.0-vc14.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_port="9000"
xdebug.remote_connect_back=true
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.collect_return="0"
xdebug.profiler_enable=0;

xdebug.remote_log="D:\xampp\logs\xdebug.log"

xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host = 192.168.1.129
```

PhpStorm:

[image]

I got this problem every 2nd or 3rd day at the moment for a few hours and just can't figure out what is going on.

Is there maybe a shortcut or anything like that, that I activated without knowing it?

Comment: Only the whole set (source code + xdebug log) may help here (so it can be checked what Xdebug sees, what command it receives and what respond it sends). If you can reproduce it on some sample simple code (and with some video screencast as well) .. then maybe Xdebug author may help you. Other than that I may only suggest to use stable xdebug version (2.6) and not alpha builds. P.S. Another thought -- some path mapping ... or debugging some cached files (that regenerated from time to time by your framework etc). No better suggestions right now.

Comment: For reference purposes: same question on PhpStorm forums: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000602950-XDebug-Remote-Debugger-seems-to-jump-to-random-locations

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for your reply! I wanted to create a sample application with logs but it works in the sample so it really seems to be some kind problem with the cached files. Still trying to figure out what cache i need to empty to fix this one.

Comment: What framework/CMS/etc do you use there? What xdebug log says (what file it goes through)? In what files in stops in IDE? Start with that.

Comment: I am using PHP 7.0 with CLI Interpreter 7.0.30 and changed to Xdebug Version 2.6.0 to ensure i got the latest stable version now. It always stops in random different .php files. The xdebug log shows the same files as the debugger jumps to.

Comment: Cannot suggest anything else with such info/details. Unfortunately such description is useless for me without knowing all the details and seeing it with my own eyes. Maybe somebody else can make a better guess.

Comment: Reinstall PhpStorm fixed the problem (for the moment). I hope it wont come up again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So i just had the problem again and it seems that removing the watches (as suggested here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000602950-XDebug-Remote-Debugger-seems-to-jump-to-random-locations) fixes it. I will keep an eye on this and post an update if the error occures again and removing the watches doesn't fix it.

Comment: can't believe i spent two hours on this.

Comment: Can't believe I nearly trashed my laptop because of this

Comment: I had a watch that included a trailing `}` like `$obj-thing}` and I'm glad I didn't spend more than 10 minutes but could have been

Comment: I had watchers setup for completely unrelated files / debuggers in another language (Go) and it broke like this. Very frustrating!

Comment: This was happening in vscode for me, so I think this is an issue with xdebug itself.

Comment: I have this problem too in visual studio code and I have no watches. Any solutions?